# Type Inference in OCaml

Tags: types, functional-programming, ocaml, ml

I'm trying to wrap my head around OCaml's type inference notation.

For example:

```
# let f x = x [];; 
val f : ('a list -> 'b) -> 'b = <fun>
```

makes sense to me. The val f takes in a function x that takes in a list of 'a type and returns something of 'b type. Then f returns a 'b type as well since it just calls x.

However, once we get more arguments I get more confused.

```
# let g a b c = a b c;;
val g : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'a -> 'b -> 'c = <fun>
```

Can I assume that if the function has arguments, then the first parameters of the type inference will always be the arguments? And if I call a b c, is the order ((a b) c) or (a (b c))?

```
# let rec h m n ls = match ls with
  | [] -> n
  | x::t -> h m (m n x) t;;
val h : ('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a = <fun>
```

As for this one I'm confused as to how ('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a was derived. I can see that 'b list corresponds to the ls variable and the last 'a corresponds to the type of the terminal symbol n.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I assume that if the function has arguments, then the first parameters of the type inference will always be the arguments?

Yes, the first parameter of function type is the type of its first argument.

> And if I call a b c, is the order ((a b) c) or (a (b c))?

The order is `((a b) c)` (you can think in this simpler way)

> As for this one I'm confused as to how ('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a was derived. I can see that 'b list corresponds to the ls variable and the last 'a corresponds to the type of the terminal symbol n.

You are right. `ls` has type `'b list` and `n` has type `'a`.

Let's think about the type of `m`:

1. You know `n` has type `'a`, so you can derive `(m n x)` also
     has type `'a`
2. You know `ls` has type `'b list`, so you can derive `x` has
     type `'b`
3. `m` takes two arguments of type `'a` and type `'b`, and produces result of type `'a`. So, `m` has type `'a -> 'b -> 'a`

Therefore, the whole function has type `('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a`

Comment: Thank you so much! That cleared up alot for me. I just had one more follow-up if you wouldn't mind answering: what if we didn't know the type inference and had to figure out just from the equation? How would you know that m's 2nd arg a.k.a. x is of type 'b and not the same as 'a?

Comment: @ChangLiu For simple function like yours, you can infer by doing unification. In a very naive way, assign ``m`` of type ``X``, ``n`` of type ``Y``,  ``ls`` of type ``Z``, etc. After that, you define equations for those variables, and solve the equations to derive the most principle types (``'a``, ``'b``, ...). You can search "Algorithm W" for more about type inference. Or, you can program in OCaml more, so you can do inference in your head faster :)